# Why is my weekly increment not working using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, increment

I have created a column called `visual date` which takes a date and works out the week start date in order for me to show a weekly increment in my visual.

Everything seems to work fine, however, I noticed when you start a new month within the week it will mess up. I.e. Once January 2022 turns to February 2022, it calculates the week start date of 01/02/2022 as 03/03/22

```
DATE(YEAR([Date]),MONTH([Date]),DAY([Date] - WEEKDAY([Date],1) +1))
```

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? If so, what formula am I supposed to be using in order to work out the weekly increment correctly

Expected Output:

Dates between `01/02/22 - 05/02/22` the visual date column should be returning `30/01/22` for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `'Table'[Date] - WEEKDAY('Table'[Date],1) + 1`.

*Update: haven't noticed in the first place, that you start with Sunday. Now its corrected.*

**Output:**

[image]

`Column2` is the new one, `Column1` is with the old formula.

Comment: Thanks that worked! One question, do you know why for me it shows the correct dates in the table view, but on the visual it shows an extra column `30/01/22` after the last date which should be `20/02/22`

Comment: Unfortunately I couln't rebuild this behavior. Maybe it'll make sense if you're opening a new question with a screenshot?